# Find and print to network printer by IP address in Java

Tags: java, sockets, printing

I've read tons of similar questions and haven't gotten anywhere..

What I'm trying to do is connect to a printer directly by IP (not one that's in my windows devices list) and print a document to it.

Here's what I've tried so far (didn't work, no idea why):

```
try{
    Socket sock = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 9100);
    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        oStream.println("Hello World");
        oStream.close();
        sock.close(); 
}
catch (UnknownHostException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what's the error message/ stack trace?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Printer Services](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html)

Comment: @chuchichaeschtli no exceptions thrown :/

Comment: The network protocol of the printer is *not* a plain text stream. It's a lot more complex than that, which is why you usually use printer device drivers in the operating system to connect to printers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for your problem. You can try your network printer with this code.

https://blog.entelect.co.za/view/3213/android-printing-to-a-network-printer

I also saw many examples just like your example worked. So I guess there could be a connection problem to printer.